# Squash two merge commits into one merge commit

Tags: git, git-merge

I have a situation where I want to squash two merge commits into one. Each merge commit contains conflict resolutions and thus `git rebase` cannot be used to my understanding. There is an option `--rebase-merges`, but I haven't figured out how it can be utilized.

The state:

```
A--\       <- feature
B--m1--\   <- branch from older master
B----C-m2  <- branch from newer master
```

The desired state:

```
A------\  <- feature
B----C--m <- branch from newer master
```

Redoing the merge of the feature branch into the newer master is not the option, since the work, which was done in `m1` will need to be repeated.

The reason for the state is that while the first merge `m1` is under review another work `C`, which conflicts with `m1`, was merged.

Any suggestions merging two merge commits into one can be performed?

Comment: The short answer is that you can't; the reason is that a merge commit does not merely contain a snapshot, it also affects the *topology* of the graph. An ordinary (squash-able) commit also contains a snapshot and a parent, but two adjacent ordinary commits have no topological effect, so they can be squashed.

Comment: @torek Thank you for your comments. It sounds that you are right. Welcome to post an elaborated answer with links to the documentation if you have time.

Comment: Why do you care about the history? If code is broken, fix the code and create a new commit. If it ain't broken, why try to fix it?